# communicate from addon main.js to page-worker

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

I'm new to the community and to developing addons.

I'm trying to fetch some data from 1 page-worker and sending it to the main addon then include some more data to it and then send it to some other page-worker.

I'm able to do the first part i.e postMessage from page-worker and receive at main addon.

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
var pageWorker = require("sdk/page-worker");
var getdata = pageWorker.Page({
    contentScript: "self.postMessage(document.body.innerHTML);",
    contentURL: "http://itildemo.servicedeskplus.com/sdpapi/request?INPUT_DATA={%22operation%22:{%22details%22:{%22status%22:%22open%22,%22from%22:0,%22limit%22:500,%22filterby%22:%22Unassigned_System%22}}}&OPERATION_NAME=GET_REQUESTS&TECHNICIAN_KEY=D357605B-E4B5-4892-A7C2-62CA556CB5A8&format=json" (http://itildemo.servicedeskplus.com/sdpapi/request?INPUT_DATA={%22operation%22:{%22details%22:{%22status%22:%22open%22,%22from%22:0,%22limit%22:500,%22filterby%22:%22Unassigned_System%22}}}&OPERATION_NAME=GET_REQUESTS&TECHNICIAN_KEY=D357605B-E4B5-4892-A7C2-62CA556CB5A8&format=json%27) ,
    contentScriptWhen: "ready"
});
getdata.on("message", function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Now is it possible to postMessage from here to other page-worker
like:

```
getdata.on("message",function(e){
     insertdata.postMessage(e);
});
var insertdata = pageWorker.Page({
     onMessage: function(e){
     console.log(e);
     }
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is very much possible to recieve message from one worker on main.js and send it to other worker. Here We have two workers.Now as soon as message recieved from pagemod worker it is sent to other worker.

```
var wsWorker = require('sdk/page-worker').Page({
    contentURL: "websocket.html",
    contentScriptFile : ["websocket.js"]
});


var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod").PageMod({
  include: ['*'],
  contentStyleFile: [self.data.url('fillStyle.css')],
  contentScriptFile: ["content.js"],
  contentScriptWhen: "start",
  attachTo: ["top", "frame", "existing"],
  onError : function(error) {
      console.log('ERROR Ocurred :- ',error);
  },
  onAttach: function(worker) {
                 worker.port.on("worker_msg",function(msg_of_other_worker){
  //send this message to another worker.
   wsWorker.port.emit("some_action",{tabUrl : msg_of_other_worker});
});
            }
});
```